# Why does graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync() return null values for some AAD profile fields that are not null?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to access user information from a UWP app. I'm using Azure App services with a client UWP app and an Azure back-end.

My Azure Active Directory only has me and a test user. The following lines in my app does return some of my info from AAD:

```
Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient =
        new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
       requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
           new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result2.AccessToken);
       return Task.FromResult(0);
}));

Microsoft.Graph.User user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

However, when i inspect the contents of the "user" variable after the call, all fields are listed as null other than DisplayName, GivenName, ID, JobTitle, AdditionalItems, and UserPrincipleName. The values that are not null are correct. However, I have also filled in the all the street address fields and provided a profile picture for my profile on AAD.  But these, too, come back null.  Can anyone tell me what could cause this?  (I checked the access token being sent with the request, and it does seem to include the required permissions.  Just to make sure, I requested all the delegate required permissions for the Windows Azure AD and the Microsoft Graph when I registered my app in AAD.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph returns a default core set of properties in each response. You can use the `$select` query parameter to get additional properties.

For example, `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` doesn't return the `streetAddress` field for a user but `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=streetaddress` returns it. You can get multiple properties back by separating the fields with commas like `$select=id,jobTitle,streetAddress`.

With the .NET SDK I believe the syntax is `Request().Select("assignedLicenses").GetAsync()` and the [documentation for this is on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#query-options).

Comment: Thanks!  This works for everything except the profile picture.  I'm still trying to figure that one out.